# Understanding function which implements foldr and foldl

Tags: list, haskell, fold, function-definition

There is some case where I don't understand how `foldr` and `foldl` are used in function.

Here is a couple of example,  I then explain why I don't understand them:

```
-- Two implementation of filter and map
map' f = foldr (\x acc -> (f x):acc) [] 
map'' f xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ [(f x)]) [] xs 

filter' f xs = foldr(\x acc -> if(f x) then x:acc else acc) [] xs 
filter'' f  = foldl(\acc x -> if(f x) then acc++[x] else acc) []
```

Why does `map''` makes the use of `xs` but non `map'`? Shouldn't `map'` need a list for the list comprehension formula as well?

Same case for `filter'` vs `filter''`.

Here is an implementation which insert elements in a sorted sequence:

```
insert e [] = [e]
insert e (x:xs)
     | e > x = x: insert e xs
     | otherwise = e:x:xs
sortInsertion xs = foldr insert [] xs
sortInsertion'' xs = foldl (flip insert) [] xs
```

Why are the argument for `insert` flipped in `sortInsertion` (`[] xs`) (empty list and list) compare to the definition of insert(e []) (element and empty list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does `map''` makes the use of `xs` but non `map'`? Shouldn't `map'` need a list for the list comprehension formula as well? Same case for `filter'` vs `filter''`.

This is called “eta-reduction” and it’s a common way of omitting redundant parameter names (“point-free style”). Essentially whenever you have a function whose body is just an application of a function to its argument, you can reduce away the argument:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y

-- “To add x and y, call (+) on x and y.”
add :: (Int) -> (Int) -> (Int)
add x y = ((+) x) y

-- “To add x, call (+) on x.”
add :: (Int) -> (Int -> Int)
add x = (+) x

-- “To add, call (+).”
add :: (Int -> Int -> Int)
add = (+)
```

More precisely, if you have `f x = g x` where `x` does not appear in `g`, then you can write `f = g`.

A common mistake is then wondering why `f x = g . h x` can’t be written as `f = g . h`. It doesn’t fit the pattern because the `(.)` operator is the top-level expression in the body of `f`: it’s actually `f x = (.) g (h x)`. You *can* write this as `f x = (((.) g) . h) x` and then reduce it to `f = (.) g . h` or `f = fmap g . h` using the `Functor` instance for `->`, but this isn’t considered very readable.

> Why are the argument for insert flipped in `sortInsertion`

The functional parameters of `foldr` and `foldl` have different argument order:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Or, with more verbose type variable names:

```
foldr
  :: (Foldable container)
  => (element -> accumulator -> accumulator)
  -> accumulator -> container element -> accumulator

foldl
  :: (Foldable container)
  => (accumulator -> element -> accumulator)
  -> accumulator -> container element -> accumulator
```

This is just a mnemonic for the direction that the fold associates:

```
foldr f z [a, b, c, d]
==
f a (f b (f c (f d z)))  -- accumulator on the right (second argument)

foldl f z [a, b, c, d]
==
f (f (f (f z a) b) c) d  -- accumulator on the left (first argument)
```

Answer (score 5):

That is partial function application.

```hs
map' f = foldr (\x acc -> (f x):acc) []
```

is just the same as

```hs
map' f xs = foldr (\x acc -> (f x):acc) [] xs
```

if you omit `xs` on both sides.

However, beside this explanation, I think you need a beginner book for Haskell. Consider [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).